# Initialized variable is null?

Tags: c#, methods, static, null, initialization

I am trying to initialize a static variable from a static method but after it has been initialized it is still null. What am I doing wrong?

```
class Database {
    public static Database Connection = null;

    public static void Create() {
        Database.Connection = new Database();

        if (Database.Connection == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Null");
        }
    }

    public Database() {
        Console.WriteLine("I got called");
    }
}
```

Am I missing something here? Database.Connection is NULL after calling the method although the constructor has been called.

Comment: Where do you notice that  it's still null? You could provide a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

Comment: Can you provide code that reproduces this, for me the code you have posted works as expected.

Comment: Are you trying to implement a singleton class?  The reference to one static instance of a the Database class that is shared by all instances of the same, Database class looks a bit odd.  (Especially as it is named Connection.)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Database {
    public static Database Connection = null;

    static Database() {
        Database.Connection = new Database();

        if (Database.Connection == null) {
            Console.WriteLine("Null");
        }
    }

    public Database() {
        Console.WriteLine("I got called");
    }
}
```

You never call the `Create()`. You can use static constructor for this, if you'd like, as I've done above.

Comment: Sorry I did not show it here but I am calling the Create() method from outside. That's why I said the method AND the constructor are being called. Database.Create() is being used in the Program.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx), to initialize static field.

```
static Database()
{
    Database.Connection = new Database();
}
```

Comment: Is this the only way to do it? Like I said in another comment, I am calling Database.Create() in the Program.cs file before doing anything else.

Comment: You should provide the code,because the code you provided,Works fine.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make the static member a Property:

```
class Database
{
    private static Database _connection = null;
    public static Database Connection
    {
        get
        {
            if(null == _connection)
            {
                _connection = new Database();
            }
            return _connection;
        }
    }
}
```

If you are implementing a singleton, then you should hide the constructor by making it private.

```
private Database()
{
    // This will only be called once, when the Connection
    // property getter is first accessed and the private 
    // _connection field is still null.  Note: when using 
    // the debugger, this may be before it is actually called
    // explicitly from within your code!
    Console.WriteLine("Database() constructor called");
}
```